# User profile redirects infinitely if you have no ascii characters in the name?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, internationalization

The page https://stackoverflow.com/users/122299/ result in Firefox saying that

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Indeed, some investigation shows the page to redirect to itself, while my page, https://stackoverflow.com/users/126214/ redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/users/126214/lennart-regebro

Thus I suspect that this user, who has no ascii character in his name, has triggered a small bug. :)

User Details on http://data.stackexchange.com
[image]

Comment: Nice catch, it'll be interesting to know what happened there!

Comment: I don't believe it has anything to do with the presence of ASCII chars in the display name - I just changed my Meta display name to my Chinese name, and I believe you should still be able to access it.

Comment: Hmm, it's working now.  Just fixed I guess.  :)

Comment: Yup, working again.

Comment: Jeff Atwood saiz: ['<waves hands> there are no bugs'](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/436945#436945)

Answer (score 2):

We no longer attempt to redirect when the name slug is empty.

Comment: It seems like this bug has found its way back: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/67/brc-%e5%af%87%e7%99%be%e5%bc%ba

Comment: (it does not work even if I remove the display name, eg: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/67/ )

Comment: @null during private beta things work differently because access is restricted. If it is a problem when the site is public, then let us know.

Comment: The issue NullUserExceptiom reports was simply a code bug related to the switch-over to the new user profile, and would affect all sites that use international URL support (on user profiles), and was not just because of the private beta. It got fixed a few days ago.