# Infinite redirect to certain questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, redirection, internationalization

In exactly the same fashion as this bug:

[User profile redirects infinitely if you have no ascii characters in the name?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74164/user-profile-redirects-infinitely-if-you-have-no-ascii-characters-in-the-name)

The same applies for questions as well.  Navigating to questions where the title in the url is empty will cause an infinite redirect loop to itself.  I stumbled across this (closed) question:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18142

Apparently this wasn't a problem (back in April 28, 2010) before since this question was closed (as shown in search).  [Revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/18142/revisions) works however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch, you're right, same issue -- we can't enforce the slug when we don't have one.